# What will happen if 0°C water is slowly added into a vacuum container adiabatically/isothermally?

Tags: phase-transition

I have thought about this question for a while. If adiabatically, according to the phase diagram, I think the water will first evaporate with temperature decreased because of the 0 pressure. I don't know what will happen if more water added? Maybe it end up as vapour-solid mix or at triple point?

I'm not sure. So could you please answer me the question: What will happen if 0°C water is slowly added into a vacuum container **adiabatically**/**isothermally**?

[image: phase diagram]

Answer (score 1):

If the transformation is isothermal, the water added first will become vapor nearly instantaneously. It will keep turning into vapor until enough water is added for the pressure to increase sufficiently to reach the triple point . If you keep adding, the vapor starts condensate in both solid and liquid until no more vapor exist.If the pressure keeps increasing, there will be a point where the solid will melt.

If this time the transformation is adiabatic, the curve described by the transformation is $P=T^{\gamma/\gamma-1}\approx T^{3.5}$ for an ideal gaz. It means that the water gets under vapor at the beginning but the temperature and the pressure both increase now. Consequently there will be a point where the vapor will turn into liquid.

The difference between adiabatic and isothermal is that the heat brought from the liquid water is kept inside the recipient in the first case but removed in the other one .